# Breusch Godfrey test, problem with matrix singularity

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, autocorrelation, singular-matrix

I am currently conducting Breusch-Godfrey tests to see if the residuals of a regression are uncorrelated. For this purpose I am backing out the residuals of the regression:
$$
X_t=B_0+B_1X_{t-1}+u_t
$$
After that, I conduct the necessary regression for the residuals:
$$
u_t=a_0+a_1X_{t-1}+a_2u_{t-1}+a_3u_{t-2}+\dots+a_{p+1}u_{t-p}+e_t
$$
My problem is now, that in this second regression the respective design matrix $(X'X)$, becomes singular for some lag amounts p. First, I thought "great" because I thought that the singularity indicates that the residuals are not only autocorrelated but that they have actual linear dependencies. However, as I proceed including further lags, at some point the singularity is not a problem anymore. As I have not excluded previous lags, the respective columns that exhibited linear relationships should still be in there. I struggle to understand how this is possible and further, I was wondering how this affects my test results.

Questions:

1. Any clue what the source of this issue might be?
2. Which lag length would you suggest using? I know there is no unified answer but how would you approach picking the right lag length?
3. Are the results of the BG test statistic still reasonable? I mean I am not interested in the right identification of the coefficients of the second regression, right? As long as the resulting coefficients lead to the same amount of explained variation, the test statistic shouldn't be bothered right?